# How to add Web3.toChecksumAddress(lower_case_address) web3.py

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3.py, solidity-0.8.x

from this code
How to add Web3.toChecksumAddress()in Web3.py
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of web3.py  you're using. As of v6, methods that were in camelCase changed to snake_case. The documentation for `to_checksum_address` is [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v6.0.0/web3.main.html#web3.Web3.to_checksum_address)